Model improvement
Whenever I try to solve some ML problem I get stuck on the first model I choose. I understand the bias-variance tradeoff, but I think it is not the only way to debug a model. Are there any tools to analyze the bottleneck of the model? Currently, I am dealing with linear regression.

Show us the data.

Here they are: https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/playground-series-s4e4/data. @J_H

I applied basic linear regression & one-hot encoding to the "Sex" feature. Generally, I am satisfied with the results. I am 1338/1546 with a 0.16389 error on the submission dataset (just a 0.02 error difference between me and the first). I wonder, how other Kaggle competitors achieve lower errors. I think it is not just the bias-variance tradeoff. @J_H
